# Charset для русского языка. PHP.HTML

Tags: php, html, charset

Я создал проект на PHP, написал в нем русские символы и у меня вместо текста вот эти калякули, что делать..

Код:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>php learning.</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
<h1>Здравствуйте</h1>
<p>
<?php
echo "Квадраты :<br />\n";
echo "<ul>\n"; 
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
echo "<li>$i В квадрате = " . ($i * $i);
echo " /// $i В кубе = " . ($i * $i * $i) . "</li>";
    }
?>
<br><br><br>
<h1>Заканчиваю работу. </h1>
</ul>
</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Локалхост:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверил на компилере от w3schools, там все нормально. что то с локалхостом, как это починить?

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

и, главное, в редакторе у Вас точно утф8? если скопировать текст отсюда Вашего кода, то он вставится корректно в редакторе?

Comment: куда вставлять эту строчку?
про вопрос я точно не понял, да у меня ютф8 

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>php learn.</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
 </head>
 <body>
```

Comment: в самом начале. до любого вывода. не забудьте открывающий тег - <?php

Comment: Код php:
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "Квадраты :<br />\n";
echo "<ul>\n"; 
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
echo "<li>$i В квадрате = " . ($i * $i);
echo " /// $i В кубе = " . ($i * $i * $i) . "</li>";
 }
?>

вид из браузера:
https://prnt.sc/whncm1

Comment: Нужно добавить первой строкой в файле этот код, до html и любого другого вывода. <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>. Так же стоит проверить чтоб файл был сохранен без BOM

Comment: Как правильно заметил камрад выше, кодировка задается **НТТР заголовком**, а не в HTML тегах.

Comment: да, а какая версия пхп?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю стоит проверить настройки php

В файле php.ini должны быть установлены следующие значения

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=6
```

Comment: может стоит определиться все-таки, в php.ini задавать кодировку или вручную отправляя заголовок?

Comment: как я понял у меня нету php, я делаю код через eclipse где сразу установлена возможность создавать php файлы, скрины:
https://prnt.sc/whriq2
https://prnt.sc/whriv4

так же изменил код на это:
```
<?php  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "Квадраты :<br />\n";
echo "<ul>\n"; 
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
echo "<li>$i В квадрате = " . ($i * $i);
echo " /// $i В кубе = " . ($i * $i * $i) . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>"

 ?>
<br><br><br>
<h1>f</h1>


 ```
Итог:https://prnt.sc/whrms2

Comment: интерпретатор в любому случае должен быть, без него код php не выполнится
как вариант стоит попробовать обновить кодировку файла и выставить в настройка ide кодировку utf-8. эта ссылка будет полезной https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse